# Backbonejs add to collection only if fetch data different

Tags: json, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I am writing a small app that calls a json request that has data about a track that is playing for a music player. Every 2-3 minutes that track on the json request changes. I am trying to get backbone to only fire and add another model to my collection if the previous entry called is different. Here is my code so far, however it keeps rendering the same data

```
// Model: Track
//
//  
window.Track = Backbone.Model.extend({});   


// Collection: Tracks
//
//  
window.Tracks = Backbone.Collection.extend({ 
    model: Track,
    url: "api/nowplaying/1.json",
    parse: function (response) {
        return response.response.body;
    }
});


// View: MetaDataView 
//
//  
window.MetaDataView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: "#metadata-template",
    tagName: 'li',
    className: 'metadata',

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.model.bind('change', this.render);
        this.initializeTemplate();
    },

    initializeTemplate: function() {
        this.template = _.template($(this.template).html());
    },

    render: function() { 
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});


// View: MetaDataLibraryView
//
//
window.MetaDataLibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'section', 
    className: 'metadata-library', 

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'startup', 'renderNew');
        this.template = _.template($('#metadata-library-template').html());
        //this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
        this.collection.on('add', this.renderNew, this);
        this.startup();
    },
    startup: function() {
        var e = this;
        window.setInterval(function () {
            console.log('fetching');
            e.collection.fetch({update: true, remove:false, add: true});
        }, 2000); 
    },
    renderNew: function(newModel) {
        var collection = this.collection;
        $metadata = this.$(".metadata-library");
        var view = new MetaDataView({ model: newModel, collection: collection });
        $metadata.append(view.render().el);
        return this;

    },
    render: function() {
        var $metadata,
            collection = this.collection;

        $(this.el).html(this.template({}));
        $metadata = this.$(".metadata-library");
        this.collection.each(function(schedule) {
            var view = new MetaDataView({ model: schedule, 
                                           collection: collection });
            $metadata.append(view.render().el);
        });

        return this;
    }
});
```

I have found posts on stackoverflow talking about the possibility of using collection fetch options like {update: true, remove:false, add: true}. How would I get the data to be rendered only if the model changes that's being fetch?

Comment: What do you mean "if the previous entry called is different"? I don't see you fetching a model anywhere. Only a collection: e.collection.fetch({...}). Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Maybe I am confused. I am referring to each collection I am fetching as having only 1 model. If that model is different it needs to add it to the collection and render it, but not rerender the rest of the already rendered models in the view

Comment: So lets say you have one model in your collection, you do a fetch, which results in a different model, which then gets added to your model. What happens then when you do another fetch then and you have 2 models in your collection? Do you want to compare it to both models in the collection, or just the most recently added one?

Comment: I want to compare it to the most recently added one. This is due to the possibility that a track might be played over again at a later date and already be in that collection. I would still need to add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
startup: function() {
    window.setInterval(function () {
        console.log('fetching');
        var track = new Track();
        track.fetch()
        .done(function() {
            if(!this.isSamePrevTrack(track)) {
                e.collection.add(track);
            }
        }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this), 2000); 
},

isSamePrevTrack: function(track) {
    if(!this.prevTrack) {
      this.prevTrack = track;
      return false;
     }
    // Do some test to see if the track is the same
    // ie. return this.prevTrack.get('id') === track.get('id');
});
```

Comment: I will try this out later but I see how this will fix my problem. Another question: When calling to create a new Track(). If model data is not different is it smart to destroy the object? Or does having a orphaned object disappear and not take up memory?

Comment: If isSamePrevTrack returns true and you don't add it to your collection the variable track should be garbage collected sometime after it falls out of scope. So no, I don't believe you need to do anything extra to ensure the runtime frees the memory allocated for track.